# SQLITE3: Error: malformed database schema (MmapStatus) - near "(": syntax error

Tags: sqlite, google-chrome, chromium

I am trying to open the "Extension Activity" database from Google Chrome and kept getting this error. I get the same error with `sqlite3`, `sqliteman` and `sqlitebrowser`. Which is odd because I am able open and query the Cookies DB. I am using Chrome 59 on Linux with Ubuntu 14.04 and sqlite 3.8.2.

> Error: malformed database schema (MmapStatus) - near "(": syntax error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version Google Chrome 59 is using is newer than my version. I was able to open and query it by downloading latest "Precompiled binaries for Linux" here https://www.sqlite.org/download.html.